# Event handlers for controls in an ASP Repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to be able to trigger events when a user clicks on a radio button that is generated within an  control on my page.

I've added an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` handler to the RadioButtonList and created a function in my code behind that should handle the selection of the RadioButtonList's ListItems, but I don't know how to pass a value to that function.
Here's my code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptQuestions">
    <HeaderTemplate><table width="100%"></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><%# Container.DataItem("QuestionText")%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblAnswerSelection" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckAnswer">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCorrectAnswer" Text="<%#Container.DataItem("CorrectAnswer") %>"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResult"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

Private Function CheckAnswer(ByVal SelectedAnswer As Integer) As Boolean
    Select Case SelectedAnswer
        Case 1 ' User answered True
            If lblCorrectAnswer.Text = "True" Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Case 0 ' User answered False
            If lblCorrectAnswer.Text = "False" Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
    End Select
End Function
```

The idea is that the user is to be informed whether or not their selected answer was correct. The value of the `CheckAnswer` function would determine a "CORRECT" or "INCORRECT" message displaying on `lblResult`. If there's a way to do this without a PostBack, then that would be ideal.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Boss has asked me to focus on another section of the project for now, I'll update as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's brief outline of client side solution (w/o post-back). Use html radio-buttons along with a hidden field to store the correct answer. Attach click event handlers on radio-buttons to match the value with the value from hidden field.

Repeater Mark-up:

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><%# Container.DataItem("QuestionText")%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="answerContainer">
            <input type="radio" class="option" name='answer_<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' value="1">True
            <input type="radio" class="option" name='answer_<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' value="0">False                
            <input type="hidden" id="correct_answer" value='<%#Container.DataItem("CorrectAnswer") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="result" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Java-script (using jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('td.answerContainer .option').click(function() {   
      var opt = $(this);
      var correctAns = opt.next('#correct_answer');
      var result = (opt.val() == correctAns.val()) ? "Correct" : "Incorrect";
      opt.parent().next('td').find('.result').html(result);
  });

});
```

*Disclaimer: untested code*

Note that radio button names are suffixed with the item index so that on the server side, you can read the user's answers by looking into the request (for example, value of `Request["answer_1"]` should tell user selected answer for second question -> "1" : True, "0": False and empty string: no selection).

The obvious disadvantage is that correct answer is stored in the html and so it will be simpler to cheat the system. Solution can be to make ajax call to the server to check if the answer is correct or not - this will need creating salted time-bound pseudo-random tokens to identify questions (otherwise user can make same ajax calls to get answers).

Answer (score 0):

Cut your RadioButton code from repeater somewhere outside repeater, go to Design view and click on that RadioButton (now it's not included in repeater and you can assign event handler to it without typing any code manually).

When you select this RadioButton in DesignView, click events button in your proporties tab and click OnSelectedIndexChanged and this will auto generate eventhandler function. You have to enable autopostback on this radiobutton (arrow in top right corner of control - in Design view).

Now cut back this RadioButton and place it inside your repeater. Now every radiobutton change will cause calling generated handler function where you can cast sender object to RadioButton, and you can access its value with SelectedValue property.

I've tried this solution many times, but only in C# so I am sorry if something is different in VB.NET

Comment: This may give me access to use pre-defined event handlers like `Page_Load`, but it doesn't allow me to specify parameters or my own functions which is what I need

Comment: I don't understand why you have to specify your own custom function? You can access radiobutton and you can get user selected value and do everything with it, call some custom functions, pass arguments to them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Function` as an event handler. It must be a `sub` which takes two argument.

Take a look at this sample.

Markup

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptQuestions">
<HeaderTemplate><table width="100%"></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><%# Eval("Name")%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" 
               ID="rblAnswerSelection" 
               RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
               AutoPostBack="true" 
               OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckAnswer">
                <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <asp:Label runat="server" 
                 ID="lblCorrectAnswer" 
                 Text='<%#Eval("CorrectAnswer") %>'>
            </asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResult"></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code-behind

```
 Public Class Data
        Public Property QuestionText As String
        Public Property CorrectAnswer As String
    End Class

    Dim lst As List(Of Data)
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            lst = New List(Of Data)
            lst.Add(New Data() With {.QuestionText = "A", .CorrectAnswer = "True"})
            lst.Add(New Data() With {.QuestionText = "B", .CorrectAnswer = "False"})
            lst.Add(New Data() With {.QuestionText = "C", .CorrectAnswer = "True"})

            rptQuestions.DataSource = lst
            rptQuestions.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub CheckAnswer(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim rad As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(sender, RadioButtonList)
        Dim item As RepeaterItem = DirectCast(rad.Parent, RepeaterItem)
        Dim correctAns As Label = DirectCast(item.FindControl("lblCorrectAnswer"), Label)
        Dim result As Label = DirectCast(item.FindControl("lblResult"), Label)
        Dim SelectedAnswer As String = rad.SelectedItem.Text
        If correctAns.Text = SelectedAnswer Then
            result.Text = "Correct"
        Else
            result.Text = "Incorrect"
        End If
    End Sub
```